# Cookies not getting passed in mobile browser in graphql request through relayjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, graphql, relayjs

I am able to send cookies in header while querying data from Graphql using this code snippet :

`Relay.injectNetworkLayer(
        new Relay.DefaultNetworkLayer(GQL_URL, {
            credentials: 'same-origin',
     }));`

**This works well for Desktop browser but not from mobile.**
But when i open my website in mobile (or simulate in chrome using any mobile model) cookies are not getting passed.

**Is there any mobile browser specific handling for cookie setting ?**

Also after analyzing cookies re getting passed in non-graphql rest api calls in mobile.

P.S.: This might not be relevant but in case of desktop, cookies are getting stored under different domain names ( As there are multiple domains for different requests):

abc.domain.com -> cookie1, cookie2...etc
def.domain.com -> cookie1, cookie2.. etc

but in mobile cookies are stored against same hostname:

abc.domain.com -> cookie1, cookie2...etc

Update: **Origin header is different in case of mobile. If it helps**

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. Changed credentials to share cross domain cookies in relayjs:

`Relay.injectNetworkLayer(
        new Relay.DefaultNetworkLayer(GQL_URL, {
            credentials: 'include',
     }));`

In case of desktop, iframe was getting loaded in contrast to mobile version where we are doing xhr request and inserting content in div after that.
So cookies were getting stored against correct domain in case of iframe because coming form correct origin but in case of xhr origin remains the same. So needed to acces through cross domain cookies.

Thanks for your help!!